# Step by step login example using spring security 3.0 with hdbc

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to Spring and Spring Security. I just need a pointer in the right direction:

I have a simple Spring MVC/Spring Security webapp. I want to add login functionality into web app. I have created following two table.

```
CREATE TABLE "users" (
  "USER_ID" NUMBER(10)  NOT NULL,
  "USERNAME" VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  "PASSWORD" VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  "ENABLED" NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("USER_ID")
)


CREATE TABLE "user_roles" (
  "USER_ROLE_ID" NUMBER(10)  NOT NULL,
  "USER_ID" NUMBER(10)  NOT NULL,
  "AUTHORITY" VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("USER_ROLE_ID"),
  CONSTRAINT "FK_user_roles" FOREIGN KEY ("USER_ID") REFERENCES "users" ("USER_ID")
)
```

I want to authenticate user from database then it checks role of the user.
I know this is dirt simple, so I just need to hear how the process should flow.

Comment: I saw this tutorial in other post and I think it's the better until this moment. <a href="http://krams915.blogspot.com.br/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-integration_18.html">Here</a> -----
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899518/looking-for-a-simple-spring-security-example
-----

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a matter of taking your time to read the [Security namespace configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html)

Here are some other resources I found useful when I was figuring this out:

- [Configuring Spring Security Form Login with Remember-Me Enabled](http://blog.richardadamdean.com/?p=213)
- [Spring Security and Wicket-auth-roles](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/spring-security-and-wicket-auth-roles.html)
- [Hashing and salting passwords with Spring Security 2](http://wheelersoftware.com/articles/spring-security-hash-salt-passwords.html)

Basically you are asking for a complete tutorial. It's better to ask about specific problems you encounter and show us what you have tried (creating two tables is a bit meagre).

And one more thing: configuring security, even with Spring, is NOT dirt simple. You have to learn about the implications of decisions you make regarding password hashing & salting, password recovery schemes and remember-me functionality to name a few common pitfalls. Also the choice of which pages/paths to secure (intercept-urls) has to be made wisely. This depends on the type of application and the context in which it runs.

Answer (score 1):

A step by step example can be found in the [spring pet clinic tutorial](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/articles/petclinic-tutorial.html).

However.

You just need to implement your own `UserDetailsService` and inject it into your security context.

[This](http://www.codercorp.com/blog/spring/security-spring/writing-custom-userdetailsservice-for-spring-security.html) is a good howto on implementing it.