# simple and understandable spring application for login

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

i am very new to spring and started to learn today only, i was searching for a simple login application which will explain the flow of the application off course spring too.

I am really unable to find one when i googled few of them are :

1. http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-spring-3-mvc-introduction-spring-mvc-framework/
2. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_hello_world_example.htm

etc..

Please do not downvote or close this question as this will help not only me but also many.

Thanks and Best Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For **simple Login Applications**:

[Spring-security-form-login-example:mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/)

[spring-mvc-login-example:roseindia](http://www.roseindia.net/spring/spring-mvc-login-example.shtml)

For **introductory tutorial** + **demo Example** + **suggested books**:
[Spring MVC Framework with Example javabeat.net](http://www.javabeat.net/2007/06/introduction-to-spring-mvc-web-framework-web-tier/)

May be this question and suggested answer can also be useful:
 [step-by-step-login-example-using-spring-security-3-0-with-hdbc:stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977575/step-by-step-login-example-using-spring-security-3-0-with-hdbc)

For beginners, they are little easy to start. You can google these tutorial easily.

Answer (score 1):

Though your question can easily be googled for answers.

I think you should try that, it will teach you how to do requirement specific search.

you may find a range of spring tutorial on

[Mkyong Site](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/)

[Login example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-password-example/)

Answer (score 0):

I can also recommend mkyongs tutorials. That one was helpful to me:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/

Also, you can autogenerate a Login form with Spring Roo and play around with that

```
roo> security setup
```

However, if you wanna get a more detailed introduction there is a webinar about Spring Security online by Mike Wiesner
http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Spring-Security-3