# how to implement when user is not login, the server should redirect to the login page in Spring

Tags: spring

I'm new to Spring3 MVC and I'm working on a web project using it, I has implemented  login and logout. I put the user info in session when user login and remove it when he logout.

Now I want to implement that:

if user login, thus he can do whatever, but if he logout and access the page which is in the server, we should redirect to the login page.

I think it's possibly using filter and some configuration in web.xml so I needn't writte much code. I think it's very easy using configuration but I don't know how to implement it.

SO How and What should I config? It's like this question a bit:[Looking for a Simple Spring security example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899518/looking-for-a-simple-spring-security-example)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In short you need FORM-BASED authentication and access-control, right ? Start with spring-security(http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/start-here.html)

Comment: Related and it might throw some light: http://loianegroner.com/2010/01/spring-security-login-and-logout-form-jsp/

Comment: I have already searched a lot of materials, I think there's something can work but too complicated, If there's a simple one, Can you tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

use - 
 return "redirect:LoginPage";