# Using Roles In Spring Boot JPA Application

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-security, user-roles

**I am currently in the process of developing a web application in Java using Spring Boot.**

What I am using for the app:

- MySQL as Data source
- Hibernate JPA for ORM
- Thymeleaf for templating

Currently my database has a table for users and roles. Login, registration and sessions are working fine.

I have created an admin-only page on the site.

I am having issues with creating and using roles for users.

> I'd like to have a role for every user in the DB and be able to use it
>   on the site. The default role on registration would be "USER", and I
>   would be able to manually change an user's role to "ADMIN" in the
>   MySQL admin.

**This is currently my User entity class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User extends Auditable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
@Email(message = "Please provide a valid e-mail")
@NotEmpty(message = "Please provide an e-mail")
private String email;

@Column(name = "password")
@Transient
private String password;

@Column(name = "first_name")
@NotEmpty(message = "Please provide your first name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "last_name")
@NotEmpty(message = "Please provide your last name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "enabled")
private boolean enabled;

@Column(name = "confirmation_token")
private String confirmationToken;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="user", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
private Role role;


public User() {
}

public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password, Role role) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.role = role;
}

/** Getters and setters */

}
```

This is my Role entity:

```
@Entity(name="role")
public class Role {

@Id
private Long id;

@OneToOne
private User user;
private Integer role;

/** Getters and setters */
}
```

Load by username in UserService:

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    if (user == null){
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username or password.");
    }
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(),
            user.getPassword(), getAuthorities(user.getRole().getRole()));
}
```

But for some reason this is not working. It creates the "role" table in the DB, and it has two rows in it

*id name

1   ROLE_USER

2   ADMIN*

Question is, **what do I need to do when I am saving the user to the DB** in order to set a role for the user I am saving? Currently none of the user rows in my table have a role column.
**And how can I make it work** so that when I have a rule in my securityconfig;

```
.hasRole("ADMIN")
```

It won't allow an user without that role to access? Currently when I try to access the page with that rule, it always returns the no access page I've configured.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking for a Simple Spring security example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899518/looking-for-a-simple-spring-security-example)

Answer (score 1):

Below is my code for implementing registration and assigning rolse to a registered user.

1) User.java (@Entity)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long user_id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean active;
    private String email;

    // user roles
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Role> roles;

    // Constructors
    private User() {}

    public User(String username, String password, String email) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
    }

    // if user is admin
    public boolean isAdmin() {
        return roles.contains(Role.ADMIN);
    }


    // Below you can generate getters & setters & toString method.

    // Getter and setter for user roles
    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

Role.java (enum type)

```
public enum Role {
    USER,
    ADMIN;

}
```

UserController.java (@Controller)

```
@Controller
public class UserController{

    //login page
    @GetMapping("/signin")
    public String loginPage() {
        return "frontend/login";
    }

    // registration page
    @GetMapping("/signup")
    public String signUpPage() {
        return "frontend/registration";
    }

    // User Registration
    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public String addUser(User user, Map<String, Object> model) {

        User userFromDB = userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername());
        if(userFromDB !=null ) {
            model.put("alreadyexists", "Username already exists!");
            return "frontend/registration";
        }

        // Set user apssword (also you can implement BCrypt)
        user.setPassword(user.getPassword());

        // set user activa
        user.setActive(true);

        // assign Rolr USER to newly registered user
        user.setRoles(Collections.singleton(Role.USER));


        userRepository.save(user);

        return "redirect:/profile";
    }
}
```

WebsecurityConfig.java (Spring Security)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http

                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/","/signup").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/signin").defaultSuccessUrl("/profile")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/signout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/signin?bye")
                    .permitAll();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, password, active FROM users WHERE username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT u.username, ur.roles FROM users u INNER JOIN user_role ur ON u.user_id = ur.user_id WHERE u.username=?");
    }
}
```

Comment: I implement it the same way but am getting stuck when trying to fetch all users for a certain role. Any idea how to do that if I also need to take care of pagination ?

Comment: Hey hi! Please create a new separate question and give a source code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, I created the question. Please help to answer. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61850249/need-to-find-all-users-for-a-specific-role-jpa-criteria-api